# Show that the integral equation $ u(x)+c\int_c^b K(x,y) u(y)dy=f(x) $ has a unique solution

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K\in L^2(a,b)^2$ (that is $\int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b|K(t,x)|^2dtds<\infty$. Let $c\in \mathbb{R}$ with $|c|<1/\|K\|$ and $f\in L^2(a,b)$. Show that the integral equation
$$
u(x)+c\int_a^b K(x,y) u(y)dy=f(x)
$$
has a unique solution $u\in L^2(a,b)$ and $$\|u\|_2\le \frac{\|f\|_2}{1-c\|K\|}$$

I have no idea about this question... Although this question looks like one from differential equation, it comes from functional analysis...

Comment: Banach’s contraction mapping fixed point theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F : L^2(a, b) \to L^2(a, b): v \mapsto f - c \int_a^b K(\cdot, y) v(y) dy.$ Note that $$\lVert F(v) - F(w) \rVert_2 = \vert c \vert \lVert \int_a^b K(\cdot, y)(v(y) - w(y)) dy \rVert_2 \leq \\ \vert c \vert \lVert K \rVert \lVert v - w \rVert_2 $$
where the last inequality follows by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Now since $\vert c \vert < \frac{1}{\lVert K \rVert},$ it follows from the contraction principle that $F$ admits a unique fixed point, i.e. a solution to the original integral equation.

Moreover, in order to prove the inequality regarding the norm of this solution, note that
$$\lVert u \rVert_2 = \lVert f - c \int_a^b K(\cdot, y) u(y) dy \rVert_2 \leq \lVert f \rVert_2 + \vert c \vert \lVert \int_a^b K(\cdot, y) u(y) dy \rVert_2 \leq \\ \lVert f \rVert_2 + \vert c \vert \lVert K \rVert \lVert u \rVert_2,$$
which by rearranging gives $\lVert u \rVert_2 \leq \frac{\lVert f \rVert_2}{1 - \vert c \vert \lVert K \rVert}.$ I hope this helps. :)